# How to find a variable with rspec tests using page.find

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec-rails

I have a test case, most of my other pages have at least one field that is just straight text and can be found using:

```
page.find("tr", text: "What I filled in").find("a.tick").click
```

This page all of the options are drop down selects, so how do I find a variable?
The rest of the syntax looks like this:

```
it "edits person job and redirects to index" do
    expect(p = FactoryGirl.create(:person)).to be_valid()
    expect(j = FactoryGirl.create(:job)).to be_valid()
    visit new_job_path
    select p.name, from: "person_job_person_id"
    select p.name, from: "person_job_job_id"
    click_button "create person job"
    page.find("tr", p).find("a.tick").click
end
```

it is unable to find the p to click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to click on the `p` element, you can easily do it with **css selector** or **xpath**:

```
find(:css, 'the css selector of your p element').click
```

or

```
find(:xpath, 'the xpath of your p element').click
```

For example

```
find(:css, 'body > div.layout > div > button').click
```

If you are using **Chrome**, you can easily find them by inspecting your element, right click on his code and copying the **css selector** or the **xpath**.