# Rspec how to write my test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

In my app where you can create tutorials I am starting to test it and I am having hard time to create correct test.

here is what I have in **spec/features/tutos/create_spec.rb**

#### How should I write the `def create_tuto` ??

```
require "spec_helper"
require "rails_helper"

context "Creating a tuto" do
  let!(:user){ User.create(first_name: "John", last_name: "Doe", email: "john@email.com", password:"password", password_confirmation:"password")
}

  def create_tuto(options={})
    options[:title]    ||= "My tuto"
    options[:category] ||= "Ruby"
    options[:content]  ||= "This contains markdown language"

    visit "en/tutos"
    click_link "create_tuto"
    expect(page).to have_content("Create your tutorial")

    fill_in "Title",  with: options[:title]
    #I don't know here how to do the dropdown select ?
    select("Ruby", from: "Chose a category")
    fill_in "Content", with: options[:content]
    click_button "Save"
  end

  it "redirect to the tuto list show page on success" do
    create_tuto
    expect(page).to have_content("Tuto was successfully created")
  end

end
```

When I launch the test I always have a problem with

```
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find link "create"
```

My **`create tuto`** is at the bottom of my partial search form:
 **views/tutos/_search_form.html.slim**

```
h1.text-gray =t("search_form.title") 
.search_banner
  .row
    .col-xs-12.col-sm-4
      =form_tag tutos_path, :method => 'get' do 
        =text_field_tag :search, params[:search],  placeholder: t("search_form.keyword"), class: 'search-form'
        =submit_tag t("search_form.search"), class:'btn btn-xs btn-default btn-search'
        br
        br

    .col-xs-12.col-sm-4
      =form_tag tutos_path, :method => 'get' do 
        =select_tag :select,
             options_for_select(User.order('nickname ASC').all.map{|u| u.nickname}, params[:select]),
             { include_blank: t("search_form.select_user"), class: 'search-form' }

        =submit_tag t("search_form.select"), class:"btn btn-xs btn-default btn-search"
        br
        br

    .col-xs-12.col-sm-4
      =form_tag tutos_path, :method => 'get' do 
        =select_tag :filter, 
              options_for_select(Category.all.map{|c| c.name}, params[:filter]),
              { include_blank: t("search_form.select_cat"),  class: 'search-form' }

        =submit_tag t("search_form.search"), class:"btn btn-xs btn-default btn-search"
        br
        br

  hr  
  .row
    .col-xs-12.col-sm-3
      = link_to t("search_form.best"),  best_voted_path, class: "btn btn-default" 

    .col-xs-12.col-sm-3
      -if user_signed_in?
        = link_to t("search_form.create"), new_tuto_path, class:"btn btn-default", id:"create_tuto"
```

**views/tutos/_tutos_form.html.slim** 
*This the partial to create a new tutorial*

```
= simple_form_for @tuto do |f|
  - if @tuto.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      h2 = "#{pluralize(@tuto.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this tuto from being saved:"
      ul
        - @tuto.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
          li = message
  = f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id
  = f.input :title, label: t('tutos_form.title')
  = f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, { include_blank: t("tutos_form.category"), class: 'search-form' }
  = f.input :content, label: t('tutos_form.content'), as: :text, input_html: { rows: "15" }
  = f.button :submit, t("tutos_form.save")
```

## EDIT

I Changed one thing in the create_tuto method:
instead of `click_link "create_tuto"`I put `click_button I18n.t("search_form.create")`

```
  def create_tuto(options={})
    options[:title]    ||= "My tuto"
    options[:category] ||= "Ruby"
    options[:content]  ||= "This contains markdown language"

    visit "/en/tutos/"
    click_button I18n.t("search_form.create")
    expect(page).to have_content("Create your tutorial")

    fill_in "Title",  with: options[:title]
    select("Ruby", from: "Chose a category")
    fill_in "Content", with: options[:content]
    click_button "Save"
  end
```

and now I have this failure:

```
Failures:

  1) Creating a tuto redirect to the tuto list show page on success
     Failure/Error: click_button I18n.t("search_form.create")

     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find button "Create a tuto"
     # /Users/nelly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.10.1/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:44:in `block in find'
     # /Users/nelly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.10.1/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:85:in `synchronize'
     # /Users/nelly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.10.1/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:33:in `find'
     # /Users/nelly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.10.1/lib/capybara/node/actions.rb:57:in `click_button'
     # /Users/nelly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.10.1/lib/capybara/session.rb:735:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Session>'
     # /Users/nelly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.10.1/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:52:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
     # ./spec/features/tutos/create_spec.rb:14:in `create_tuto'
     # ./spec/features/tutos/create_spec.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

### Maybe this could help !

### The button " Create Tuto"  requires a signed in user to be displayed

How can I write the test then ??

Comment: can you try with `page.find("create_tuto").click ?

Comment: it says: `Failure/Error: page.find("create_tuto").click

     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find css "create_tuto"`

Comment: can you add a `p current_url`just before clicking on "create_tuto" ? just to be sure you are in the page where the link is

Comment: you mean in test right?

Comment: `visit "en/tutos" p current_url click_link "create_tuto"`

Comment: Failure/Error: click_link "create_tuto"

     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find link "create_tuto"
     # /Users/nelly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.10.1/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:44:in `block in find'
and more lines to long to enter here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125351/discussion-between-nelly-johan-and-fabersky).

Comment: ok but can you find the current_url printed in terminal?

Comment: $ rspec spec/features
."http://www.example.com/en/tutos"
F.

Failures:

  1) Creating a tuto redirect to the tuto list show page on success
     Failure/Error: click_link "create_tuto"

Comment: so is "example.com/en/tutos" the right page?

Comment: It is the right page yes

Comment: please try to click the element using this http://stackoverflow.com/a/34204391/1033737

Comment: Shall i do this  `find(:css,"create_tuto").click` as I've added an **id** to my link_to ?

Comment: If you are using Chrome, you can easily the css selector by inspecting your element, right click on his code and copying the css selector, then paste it in your find("").click

Comment: when create tuto is clicked normally it open the  tutos/new.html.slim with the _tutos_form.html.slim

Comment: I did your suggestion with Chrom inspection and I have:
<a class="btn btn-default" id="create_tuto" href="/en/tutos/new">Create a tuto</a>