# Multiple selectors using have_selector

Tags: capybara, capybara-webkit

I wish to convert my find's to using have_selector. Presently I have this working as:

```
expect(find('div[some-attr=true]'))['some-data-attr']).to eq('Hello World')
```

I wish to convert this to use have_selector and I tried:

```
expect(page).to have_selector('div[some-attr=true][some-data-attr]')
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: have you tried with the css selector? http://stackoverflow.com/a/34204391/1033737 . in your case, it would be `expect(page).to have_selector(YOUR_DIV_SELECTOR)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be

```
expect(page).to have_css('div[some-attr=true][some-data-attr="Hello World"]')
```

This will only work if 'some-data-attr' isn't actually a property that has been modified since the page load.  The selectors match on attribute values, but since your original method calls `#[]` on a returned element it could have been accessing a property with a changed value. Without knowing what those attribute names actually are and how they've been used it's impossible to say for sure.  If it is actually a property and you need to use it a lot in your app you could write a custom filter on the :css selector

If Capybara.default_selector == :css then `have_selector` and `have_css` mean the same thing, but if you're using a css selector then you're better off just using `have_css`

Answer (score 0):

For me worked like this:

```
expect(first("div.flex-cal-day-event-bar.flex-cal-day-event-bar--day-span-1[data-behaviour='event-listing']")).to have_content(text)
```